# How to disable default association of optional arguments in the subroutine argument list?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, optional-arguments

My existing subroutine `A(a,b,c,d,e)` is working fine where
`a,b,c` are the actual arguments and `d` and `e` are optional arguments.

Many other subroutines call subroutine `A` such as

```
call A(a,b,c)
```

or

```
call A(a,b,c,d=2.0D0)
```

or

```
call A(a,b,c,e=1.0D0)
```

Now.

I have decided to remove `c` from subroutine `A`.

So it becomes

```
subroutine A(a,b,d,e)
```

When I recompile the codes, lines such as

```
 call A(a,b,c,e=1.0D0)
```

was not complained by the compiler, which is not
what I want. Now, it thinks c is the
optional argument `d` of new subroutine `A(a,b,d,e)`

I could search for all occurrences of subroutine A in all my codes to 
avoid such wrong interpretation, but I miss even one of them I am going
to pay a big price dearly (wrong results, anguish moments, ...), but a good trick to let to 
compiler complain and I fix them necessarily.

This brings to my question. How to ask the compiler NOT to assume
default association of optional variables unless I put in a `=` sign? I.e., if I want to 
use an optional variable, I will pass it as `c=2.0D0`, `e=3.0D0`. 
Without = sign, is there a way to make it a default non-optional 
argument?

This way, the compiler would certainly complains since `c` is not 
matching any existing variable in the modified subroutine.

Comment: Welcome. Please do read [tour] and [ask]. Proper formatting will make your post much better. Use tag [tag:fortran]. You can add a [tag:fortran90] if you want to limit the answers to the old and obsolete Fortran 90 (typically you do not want that).

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable this behaviour. Fortran standard rules require this. You would have to use a different language, but not Fortran.

To prevent this you can use named arguments for all your arguments in the argument lists in all calls.

Furthermore, there are tools to help with changes with restructuring your code ([code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)). You could also just use simple `grep` and `sed` or the search and replace feature of your code editor (it should be able to search in the whole project or directory).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps as a temporary measure before you remove the argument, change the type of the dummy argument C to be something different - for example make it an object of a derived type that you create specially for that argument.  If you recompile with that changed type in the procedure definition, the compiler will flag procedures that still have an positional argument corresponding to C.

(If the derived type that you use for C is not accessible outside of the module that defines the procedure, then this approach is a way of forcing clients of your code to always use named actual arguments in a procedure reference.)

For example:

```
subroutine proc(a, b, c, d, e)
  real :: a, b, c, d, e
  optional :: d, e
  ...
```

goes to

```
type, private :: dummy
end type dummy

subroutine proc(a, b, c, d, e)
  real :: a, b, d, e
  type(dummy) :: c
  optional :: c, d, e
```

Comment: This is the kind of *temporary measure* which becomes an inscrutable maintenance issue for the next generation of programmer.  I wonder if SO will be around long enough for the question *I have a Fortran 2008 program which contains an empty derived type which seems to be used as the optional argument to a number of subroutines.  Can anyone tell me what the Fortran is going on ?*  :-)